# generate shared secret key in iTunes Connect for in app purchase?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I'm trying to add an auto-renew subscription to my app through iTunes connect.  In the developer center pdf it shows a screenshot in the 'Manage In-App purchase' section where you can click on 'Generate Shared Secret Key'.  My iTunes connect screen does not have this.  Is this something that's being rolled out to developers?  Also, I have agreed to the new app store TOS so don't think that's the issue.

Comment: I figured it out.  I had to go into the 'Contracts' section of iTunes connect and accept the new addendum.  Once I did that I was able to see an option for generating a shared secret key.

Comment: I can see **Manage In App Purchase**. But no **Generate Shared Secret Key**
Even i checked with **CONTRACTS**, and there is nothing to accept ( can see two REQUEST buttons)

Comment: Closing this as you figured it out (and it is off topic).

Comment: SOLUTION Try this :Once u login to itunes connect account check your right bottom side of webpage so you can see headings like "video tutorials ,manage your app etc"  In that "manage your app" option click the 3rd sub option "In-App Purchases Shared Secret" link.Then you can generate key

Comment: Here is answer [To generate a shared secret](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide/Chapters/CreatingInAppPurchaseProducts.html) -> 1. Open the App. 2. Click Features. 3. From In-App Purchases, click View Shared Secret. 4. Click Done.

Comment: @Ramis Thanks I found exact place for shared secret. So I require to deliver this shared secret to customer server so it can query about renewable products to apple server ?

Comment: @Siddharth Yes. You need to deliver shared secret to customer server.

Comment: @Ramis thank you for your quick reply.